# Get Center of Geometry in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, centroids

Given a `Geometry` object in OpenLayers 3. How would one go about getting its center?

Older versions of OpenLayers provided a `getCentroid` method. There was also a `getBounds` workaround. But these appear to be removed in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bit of a workaround but you can use the `getExtent` method on the geometry to set the extent on the map. I presume the center of the view will then be the center of the geometry;

```
Test = new ol.geom.Geometry();
map.getView().fitExtent(Test.getExtent, map.getSize());
var CenterOfGeom = map.getView().getCenter()
```

If you do not want to change the view (which I can imagine), you can think of a function to calculate the center of the extent. This will be easy in certain types of coordinate systems (EPSG:3857, which is meter based), but more difficult in others (EPSG:4326, based on lon/lat coords). A function which could calculate this center (in EPSG:3857) would be as following;

```
function getCenterOfExtent(Extent){
var X = Extent[0] + (Extent[2]-Extent[0])/2;
var Y = Extent[1] + (Extent[3]-Extent[1])/2;
return [X, Y];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it should be

`var x = extent[0] + (extent[2] - extent[0]) / 2;

 var y = extent[1] + (extent[3] - extent[1]) / 2;`

Comment: Yes you are right, small mistake there, changed my awnser

Comment: Something so trivial should just be shipped with OL3. +1 for the agnostic `getCenterOfExtent`

Comment: @Joel Hey, now it is. OL version 3.9.0 has **`ol.extent.getCenter`** and its stable. For example, I did `var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
  var oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);` and gave me the center of points, lines and polygons. Check it out [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html?stableonly=true#getCenter)

Comment: That is actually quite good :)

Answer (score 22):

You can get its extent center using **`ol.extent.getCenter`**. In my case I have a vector layer and I want to get the center of a feature after I click it.

So

create a simple click interaction and add it to the map

```
 var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
 map.addInteraction(select);
```

For each click...

```
select.on('select', function(e) {
```

Get the first feature that is selected, from the "selected" array. Then get its geometry, and then its extent.

Use that extent to find its center, using `ol.extent.getCenter`

```
    var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
    var oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);
    console.log("The center is :  "+oo); // voila!!!!

 });
```

The same code worked for lines, points, and polygons.

PS. The `ol.extent.getCenter` is stable, used in OL version 3.9.0 and version 3.10.1 and can you can find it [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html#.getCenter)

Comment: For lines, this will get you the center of the extent occupied by line geometry.  To get a point that is actually on the line, you can use e.selected[0].getGeometry().getClosestPoint(oo)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the center with:

```
var center = e.feature.getGeometry().getCenter();
```

Comment: In which version of OpenLayers 3 does this work? In 3.15.1, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: feature.getGeometry(...).getCenter is not a function`.

Comment: The `getCenter()` method is only applicable to circle geometries `ol.geom.Circle`. Is it possible that you have a different type of geometry?

Comment: Yep, I tried it with a LineString, good to know that this only works with circles. For LineStrings, however, one can use the code in @slevin's answer which will return the point "in the middle of the line".

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers v 6.1.1

`var center = e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent().getCenter()`

Comment: This is center of extent, not center of geometry as requested in question.

Comment: I don't think this will get you the centroid of the geometry, it will get you the center of the extent occupied by line/polygon geometry.